# How can I change the parameter signature in the help docs of a decorated function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, functools

I have a class that includes a method that takes two parameters, `a` and `b`, like so:

```
class Foo:
  def method(self, a, b):
    """Does something"""
    x, y, z = a.x, a.y, b.z
    return do(x, y, z)
```

When running `help(Foo)` in the Python REPL, you would see something like this:

```
class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  method(self, a, b)
 |      Does something
```

I have updated the class with a decorator that manipulates the arguments passed into the method so instead of taking `a` and `b` and unpacking them, the decorator will do the unpacking and pass `x`, `y`, and `z` into the method:

```
def unpack(fn):
  def _unpack(self, a, b):
    x, y, z = a.x, a.y, b.z
    return fn(self, x, y, z)
  return _unpack

class Foo:
  @unpack
  def method(self, x, y, z):
    """Does something"""
    return do(x, y, z)
```

This works fine except that the help string isn't very helpful anymore:

```
class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  method = _unpack(self, a, b)
```

The standard way to fix this is to use `functools.wraps`:

```
from functools import wraps

def unpack(fn):
  @wraps(fn)
  def _unpack(self, a, b):
    x, y, z = a.x, a.y, b.z
    return fn(self, x, y, z)
  return _unpack
```

And that works great, too, *except* that it shows the method as taking `x`, `y`, and `z` as arguments, when really it still takes `a` and `b` (that is, 2 arguments instead of 3), so the help doc is a bit misleading:

```
class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  method(self, x, y, z)
 |      Does something
```

**Is there a way to modify the function wrapper so it correctly grabs the doc string and other attributes as in `functools.wraps` *but* also shows the arguments accepted by the wrapper?**

For example, I would like the help string to show:

```
class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  method(self, a, b)
 |      Does something
```

even when the method is wrapped by `unpack`.

(I have examined the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13aefd175e3c04529251f175c23cb3ed88451fd0/Lib/functools.py#L65) of `functools.wraps` but I could not figure out if that can copy the function signature or not.)

Comment: Your intro was a bit confusing. So to be clear: You want 1) the undecorated `Foo.method` to have three parameters `x`, `y`, and `z`, and 2) the wrapper replacing it after decoration to be given the original `method` docstring, but 3) for that wrapper to also to retain its own parameter signature of `a` and `b`?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct and so is your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Delete the `__wrapped__` attribute that is added automatically by [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) before returning the wrapper:

```py
def unpack(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self, a, b):
        x, y, z = a.x, a.y, b.z
        return fn(self, x, y, z)
    del wrapper.__wrapped__  # <-- force inspection to show `wrapper` signature
    return wrapper
```

---

## Details

The built-in [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function is just a a wrapper around [`pydoc.help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html), which in turn is just an instance of [`pydoc.Helper`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/pydoc.py#L2210).

Skipping over a few steps, it turns out that eventually for rendering the documentation for any kind of function, the [`TextDoc.docroutine`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/pydoc.py#L1460) method is called. And that in turn utilizes [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) to retrieve the signature of the function in question (see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/pydoc.py#L1494)).

All it does then is take the string representation of that `Signature` object, adds a bit more stuff, and glues the docstring underneath it.

The docstring is essentially just the `__doc__` attribute of the function object in question, which `functools.wraps` (or more precisely [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper)) copies over from the "actual" function. This is why using the `@wraps` decorator solves the docstring issue.

The problem for you is that `update_wrapper` also *always* adds the `__wrapped__` attribute to the wrapper function and assigns the original function to that. Turns out that the `inspect` library knows this and is on the lookout for that attribute. The idea presumably being that you usually want to inspect the "actual" underlying function, not the wrapper, since you took the time to use `update_wrapper` in the first place.

The [`inspect.unwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.unwrap) method is used to drill down to the non-wrapped function before analyzing that and retrieving its parameter specification. Therefore the straightforward solution is to simply get rid of the `__wrapped__` attribute on your wrapper function so that `inspect` will be forced to analyze that.

It should be obvious, but the `__wrapped__` attribute is added for a reason: To still have access to the original function after decoration. So while this does solve your problem, it may introduce other problems.

---

## PS

Taking this one step further, you could theoretically keep the `__wrapped__` attribute, but assign it a stub with any signature you want. This will "fool" the `inspect` tools into returning the signature of that stub, which will in turn end up in the auto-generated documentation from `pydoc`/`help`.

For example:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

R = TypeVar("R")
T = TypeVar("T")


class HasXY(Protocol):
    x: int
    y: str


class HasZ(Protocol):
    z: float


def unpack(fn: Callable[[T, int, str, float], R]) -> Callable[[T, HasXY, HasZ], R]:
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(self: T, a: HasXY, b: HasZ) -> R:
        x, y, z = a.x, a.y, b.z
        return fn(self, x, y, z)

    def _signature(self, a: HasXY, b: HasZ):  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        raise NotImplementedError
    __annotations__ = getattr(fn, "__annotations__", {})
    for name in ("self", "return"):
        if name in __annotations__:
            _signature.__annotations__[name] = __annotations__[name]
    wrapper.__wrapped__ = _signature  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

    return wrapper
```

```py
class Foo:
    @unpack
    def method(self, x: int, y: str, z: float) -> None:
        """Does something"""
        print(f"method({x=}, {y=}, {z=})")


help(Foo)


class Bar:
    x = 1
    y = "a"


class Baz:
    z = 3.14


foo = Foo()
foo.method(Bar, Baz)
```

Output:

```
Help on class Foo in module __main__:

class Foo(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  method(self, a: __main__.HasXY, b: __main__.HasZ) -> None
 |      Does something
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  ...

method(x=1, y='a', z=3.14)
```

The code above will incidentally pass `mypy --strict` without errors.

Again, this is somewhat hack-ish, in that that the method's `__wrapped__` attribute is now just a reference to the `_signature` stub, so you will not be able to call the original method *directly* in any way.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I was 99% sure it had something to do with the `__wrapped__` attribute's interaction with the `help()` function, but I couldn't drill down deep enough to find out how the `help()` function interacted with it, so thanks for the in-depth answer.